# How do you format dates from JS objects in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, date-formatting

I am using the ng2-daterangepicker module in my Angular 2 app.  The module returns an object, however I need a YYYY-MM-DD format.

I would use a date pipe, however I don't think it is possible to use with the module, as the HTML does not use a regular variable.  The module does have settings to set the format, but it doesn't seem to work properly - I still receive an object.

.format does not work, as Angular 2 is in typescript.  I have tried .toString(), which does return a date in this format:  Wed Mar 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 - but I am not sure how I would then convert that to the format I need.

**HTML**

```
            <input type="text" name="daterangeInput" daterangepicker [options]="options" (selected)="selectedDate($event)"/>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
   startDate: any;
   endDate: any;

   private selectedDate(value: any) {

    this.startDate = value.start.toString();
    console.log(this.startDate);

    this.endDate = value.end.toString();
    console.log(this.endDate)
    // console.log(value.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
}


  constructor(

      private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
      private ngZone: NgZone,
      private http: Http,
      private daterangepickerOptions: DaterangepickerConfig

   ) {

    this.daterangepickerOptions.settings = {
      locale: { format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' },
      alwaysShowCalendars: false
  };


}
```

I'm new to Angular 2.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native date formats are not always handled properly by browsers.
You could use 'momentjs' library
[MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/)

After the library is installed you should imported in your component and use it.

```
 import * as moment from 'moment';
....

moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```